# Questions on Docker Build and Local Docker Repo

Tags: docker, rhel7

I am trying to create a docker image using the below command .

```
docker build -t mytestapp .
```

My `DockerFile` looks like this

```
# Set the base image
FROM rhel7:latest
USER root

# Dockerfile author / maintainer 
MAINTAINER Name <email.id@example.com> 

# Update application repository list and install the Redis server. 
RUN mkdir /usr/local/myapp/
ADD myapp-0.0.1-jar /usr/local/myapp/

RUN java -Dspring.profiles.active=qa -jar /usr/local/myapp/myapp-0.0.1.jar

# Expose default port
EXPOSE 8080
```

Questions:

1) Is it fine the way I am adding the `JAR` file. Will it be available inside `/usr/local` on the `container` after I prepared am image from the above build.

2) When I build the image using `docker build` command , is the build image is pushed to docker repository hub by default.

Since the WAR file contains credentials, I don't want to push the image to Docker Hub but we would like to push to our local Docker registry using Docker distribution and pushing with `docker push`.

Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questions:

1. Docker recommends using the `COPY` instructions for adding single files into an image. It will be available inside the container at `/usr/local/myapp/myapp-0.0.1-jar`
2. When you build the image it will be available on your local docker-host. It won't leave the server unless you explicitly tell it so.

Another tip I want to give you is the recommended docker image naming convention, which is `[Repository/Author]/[Imagename]:[Version]`.

So for your image it might be called `zama/mytestapp:1.0`

If you want to push it into your local registry, you'll have to name your image after the syntax `[LocalRegistry:Port]/[Repository/Author]/[Imagename]:[Version]`.

So your image might now be called `registry.example.com:5000/zama/mystestapp:1.0`

If you have authentication on your registry, you need to `docker login` first and then simply push the image with `docker push registry.example.com:5000/zama/mystestapp:1.0`.